# How to check if a CSV file is empty and to add data to it in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have created a CSV file and it is currently empty. My code checks whether if the CSV file contains data or not. If it doesn't, it adds data to it. If it does, it doesn't do anything. This is what I tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
if df.empty:
    #code for adding in data
else:
    pass #do nothing
```

But when implemented, I got the error:

```
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Is there a better way to check if the CSV file is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

try:
   #file.csv is an empty csv file
   df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
   #Code to adding data
else:
   pass  #Do something
```

Comment: This worked when I first added data (about 100 columns) to my CSV file (1KB size) via the code above. But, when I delete all the data in my CSV file and try again (it shows 80 KB now), I am getting the error:
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from files. What's the reason for this? How can I combat it?